# SQL SELECT WHERE row contains word

Tags: php, mysql, select

i need to select from row where contains word `limit 1`, and echo it out.

So for example, i have in row categories more than `1000 cars` which `200` with the same name, i only want to select from each car only one.

```
SELECT * FROM brands
WHERE car (bmw,audi,mercedes )
```

And sort by newest added

Comment: Start with [this link](http://www.sqlcourse.com/) to SQL tutorials

Comment: Show some code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

## No duplicates

You want to DISTINCT or GROUP BY mysql statement:

- DISTINCT: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp
- GROUP BY: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

The statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM cars
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM cars GROUP BY name
```

returns no duplicate names

## Subqueries

As shown in other answers you can use WHERE IN to filter on an set of data:

```
WHERE `column` IN ('item`1', 'item2', ..)
```

you can also use this to subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brandId IN (SELECT Id FROM brands WHERE name IN ('BMW', 'Volkwagen', ..)
```

reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 0):

First, you select `car` that is `IN` `('bmw', 'audi', 'mercedes')`. To select same car only once, use `GROUP BY car`. In the end you have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `brands` WHERE `car` IN ('bmw', 'audi', 'mercedes') GROUP BY `car` ORDER BY `date_added`
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE columnName LIKE '%bmw%'
OR columnName LIKE '%audi%'
OR columnName LIKE '%mercedes%'
```

you can change `OR` to `AND` operator depend your condition.

Answer (score -2):

This will help you out:

```
SELECT * FROM brands WHERE car IN ('bmw' , 'audi' , 'mercedes') GROUP BY car ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Comment: Same question for my response... :P