# Fastest way for selecting something like this

Tags: php, mysql, select, while-loop

I want to select faster than this my page load is very slow when executing the script.

```
$bmw= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name='bwm' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"); $mercedes= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cars
WHERE name='mercedes' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"); 
$audi= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name='audi'
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"); 
$skoda= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name='skoda' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
```

And echo it out like here below, like that the page load is very slow.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($bmw)) { echo $row['name'] . " " .
 $row['date'];

 }

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mercedes)) { echo $row['name'] . " "
 . $row['date'];

 }

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($audi)) { echo $row['name'] . " " .
 $row['date'];

 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your queries should be fast, so I suppose that columns name and/or date are not indexed.

Comment: Thanks, but is this good like this ?

Comment: Have you run an EXPLAIN on the queries? Hav eyou looked at the indexes on the tables?

Comment: you won't find too many 'bmw' with this code :-)
Apart from that, if you only use the columns 'name' and 'date' within the program, it's a good idea to only select those columns.

Comment: @Ronald Thanks, i only want to select one from each car i have in the database and make a link from it bmw.php wit all the cars.

Comment: @Tasos I was just referencing to the fact that you misspelled bmw a few times. The second statement was just a general advice. Only select the columns you need. That's good practice as it improves understandability of your code, makes the code more robust (depending on the language) and saves a bit of perfomance.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the queries you wrote, your performance issue may be due to :

- missing indexes on name and date : create indexes on name and date
- cars database too big for your hardware : new hardware/partitionning/redesign
- network link slow : solution provided by Lacy K is interesting as there is only one query sent to mysql

You could also improves performance a bit by selecting only name and date instead of *

```
select name, date from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not selecting all make at once like this:

```
$q= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name IN ('bwm', 'mercedes', 'audi', 'skoda') ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"); 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) { 
     if($row['name'] == 'bmw'){
      echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['date'];
     }
     elsif($row['name'] == 'mercedes'){
      echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['date'];
     }
     elsif($row['name'] == 'audi'){
      echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['date'];
     }
     elsif($row['name'] == 'skoda'){
      echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['date'];
     }
     else{
      echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['date'];
     }

    }
```

Comment: He was told this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507733/sql-select-where-row-contains-word

Comment: Ok, I did not search the site for his questions so I didn't know others already suggested this to him. I was simply answering this question which doesn't have any links to that question.